# importing gcp resource into terraform fails even if the resource exists

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to import existing gcp compute instance into with `terraform import` command.
But I am encountering this error which says the resource does not exist while using the import command as :

```
 terraform import google_compute_instance.tf-instance-2 my_project_id
```

```
google_compute_instance.tf-instance-2: Import prepared!
  Prepared google_compute_instance for import
google_compute_instance.tf-instance-2: Refreshing state... [id=projects/qwiklabs-gcp-02-67a8ccc33dba/zones/us-central1-a/instances/qwiklabs-gcp-02-67a8ccc33dba]
╷
│ Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object
│
│ While attempting to import an existing object to "google_compute_instance.tf-instance-2", the provider detected that no object exists with the given id. Only pre-existing objects can be imported; check that the id is correct and that it is
│ associated with the provider's configured region or endpoint, or use "terraform apply" to create a new remote object for this resource.
╵
```

But when I list the available gcloud compute instances `tf-instance-2`(the instance I am trying to import) is there.

```
NAME: tf-instance-1
ZONE: us-central1-a
MACHINE_TYPE: n1-standard-1
PREEMPTIBLE:
INTERNAL_IP: 10.128.0.3
EXTERNAL_IP: 34.121.38.65
STATUS: RUNNING

NAME: tf-instance-2
ZONE: us-central1-a
MACHINE_TYPE: n1-standard-1
PREEMPTIBLE:
INTERNAL_IP: 10.128.0.2
EXTERNAL_IP: 35.184.192.60
STATUS: RUNNING
```

The instances that I am trying to import are automatically created by GCP's codelabs.
My main.tf consists of only 3 blocs, `terraform, google provider and google_compute_instance` resource.
Things I have tried:

- Changing the versions of terraform and google provider
- `terraform init` and `terraform init -refconfigure` before running the import commands.
- Make sure all the attributes of are instances are in terraform.

main.tf file:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "4.8.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
  zone    = var.zone
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "tf-instance-2" {
  name = "tf-instance-2"
  #   id = "4193295884192005746"
  project      = var.project_id
  zone         = var.zone
  machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
  labels = {
    "goog-dm" = "qldm-10079641-937281f7192921b3"
  }
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-10-buster-v20220118"
    }
  }
  network_interface {
    network = "default"
    access_config {

    }
  }
  allow_stopping_for_update = true
  metadata_startup_script   = <<-EOT
        #!/bin/bash
    EOT
}
```

Answer (score 8):

According to the `import` documentation for `google_compute_instance`:

> Instances can be imported using any of these accepted formats:

```
$ terraform import google_compute_instance.default projects/{{project}}/zones/{{zone}}/instances/{{name}}
$ terraform import google_compute_instance.default {{project}}/{{zone}}/{{name}}
$ terraform import google_compute_instance.default {{name}}
```

`name` would probably be easiest here, and so we can modify the `import` command to target it accordingly:

```
terraform import google_compute_instance.tf-instance-2 tf-instance-2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$ terraform import google_compute_instance.tf-instance-2 {{my_project_id}}/{{zone}}/tf-instance-2
```

like is a documentation

```
$ terraform import google_compute_instance.default projects/{{project}}/zones/{{zone}}/instances/{{name}}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

landed here and [previous Matt's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70879992/1894553) gave us the hint.

to add some value, if you're using **google-shell**, beware its being launched on a specific project, so if you want to **import cross-project resources** it's required to add the `projects/{{project}}/` or `{{project}}/` prefix.

pretty obvious but got us some headaches, hope it helps someone

Comment: It helped me.  I used the full path and it worked, ie.
terraform import google_compute_instance.tf-instance-2 {{my_project_id}}/{{zone}}/tf-instance-2

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, with an initial Terraform API call resulting in status code 409, `Error: Error creating Service: googleapi: Error 409: Requested entity already exists`. Thinking that if it already exists, I should import it, I was then presented with OP's error `Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object`.

In the case of Cloud Monitoring services, the name is far from simple. To find it, I had to navigate to [Cloud Monitoring services](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/services), select the three dots at the end of the relevant service's row, choose Edit Display Name, and then copy the name out of the displayed JSON. The name wound up having the form, `projects/<project_number>/services/wl:<project_name>-zone-<zone>-<cluster_name>-<namespace>-Deployment-<deployment_name>` (this is for a GKE Workload).